# If a system of linear equations is inconsistent, what does it mean geometrically?

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have a system:

$$ 
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
ax+by+z = 1\\
x+aby+z=b\\
x+by+az=1
\end{array}
\right.
$$

What would be the best way to discuss it?
Here's how I started (I used Kronecker–Capelli theorem):
First we create a cofactor matrix:
$$(A|B) = \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
a & b & 1 & 1\\
1 & ab & 1 & b\\
1 & b & a & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Then we try to get rank of the matrix to check the system consistency in different cases:

$$rank(A|B) = rank\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
a & b & 1 & 1\\
1 & ab & 1 & b\\
1 & b & a & 1
\end{array}
\right)=rank
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
a & b & 1 & 1\\
0 & b(a-1)(a+1) & a-1 & ab-1\\
0 & b(a-1) & (a-1)(a+1) & a-1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Now we can see that for $a=1$ we have to cases:
1) if $b≠1$, the system is inconsistent.
2) if $b=1$ we have a two-parametric solution:
$$x+y+z=1$$ $$x=1-y-z\\y,z∈R$$
so
$$(x,y,z)=(1-y-z, y, z); y,z∈R$$
Now, what happens if $a≠1$? I got stuck here and I'm not sure where the condition will lead me? Is there maybe a better way of discussing this system?

And now, the biggest question: What do each of the cases mean geometrically? If the system is inconsistent, does it mean that the planes are parallel? (lol)
What does it mean if the system has infinite number of solutions and what does it mean if there's only one solution? Thank you for your time.

Comment: If we take the easiest inconsistent system of linear equations, namely the linear equation $0=1$ - what does it mean geometrically ?

Comment: It doesn't make sense. It means that origin and 1 on the x-axis are the same points, doesn't it?

Comment: Every inconsistent system over a field has an equation equivalent to  $0=1$.

Comment: Does it mean that my steps are incorrect, since I multiplied row 2 and 3 by $a$ and subtracted row 1 from them, before I made a condition that $a≠0$? Later on I added that case and got the same result as if I added it in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Geometrically, it may mean that one of the planes is parallel to one of the others, or perhaps none of them are parallel, but they form an infinite triangular prism (i.e. each pair of planes intersects in a line, producing three parallel lines).

In terms of what to do in the case of $a \neq 1$, I would consider the case $a = 0$, then I would consider the case where $a$ is not equal to $0$ or $1$. In this case, you are allowed to divide by $a - 1$ and $a$, so I would divide the top row by $a$, and the middle and bottom rows by $a - 1$.

Comment: One more question: Generally, if we have a two-parametric system of equations which we have to discuss, do we choose one "main" parameter and for every "critical" case of that parameter, we have sub-cases for the second parameter? Will the system be fully discussed then?

Comment: If you're asking what I think you're asking, then yes. Basically, when I analyse these families of systems of equations, where the families are indexed by one or more variables, I try to row reduce, as usual, while avoiding division for as long as possible. When there's nothing left to do but divide by a number, I split into two cases: what if the number is $0$, and what if it isn't. This may have to happen several times, but by the time you've considered all the cases, you've completely discussed the behaviour of the family of systems.

Comment: Is there a word for three planes forming a prism? It seems analogous to being parallel.

Comment: There's no term that I know of, but I'd be very interested to hear if there is!

Answer (score 1):

A solution consists of the set of points common to the three planes. Here the number of solutions is either $0, 1$ or $\infty$, and can either be a point, a line, or a plane ( if the 3 planes are equal).

If there is a solution where the planes are pairwise transversal (other than the three planes being equal), then the planes intersect at a point. The dimension of the intersection set is the dimension of the ambient space (which I assume is $\mathbb R^3$  minus the sum of the codimensions of the planes ( each has codimension $1$ in $\mathbb R^3$. This means the intersection has dimension: $3-1-1-1 =0$

The solution may be a line too: imagine the standard $x-y, x-z, y-z$-planes in your standard Cartesian coordinate system.

If the solution is a plane, then all planes are equal.

If there is no solution, it means , as Theo Bendit said that either the 3 planes are parallel ( same normal vector up to scaling) , or exactly two of them coincide. This exhausts all possibilities.

EDIT: As pointed by Brian Scott, and indicated in Theo's post, there is also the possibility that the three planes will form an infinite prism.

Comment: I have one more question: Basically, if $rankA ≠ rank[A|B]$, the system is inconsistent. Let's take an example when we have a system of three equations, there are six cases for the system to be inconsistent. Could you please discuss these three cases geometrically?
1) If $rankA = 2$ and $rank[A|B]=3$;
2) If $rankA = 1$ and $rank[A|B]=3$;
3) If $rankA = 1$ and $rank[A|B]=2$;
4) If $rankA = 0$ and $rank[A|B]=3$;
5) If $rankA = 0$ and $rank[A|B]=2$;
6) If $rankA = 0$ and $rank[A|B]=1$;

Comment: @A6Tech: OK, please give me some time, I am a bit busy now, but will come back later.

Comment: @A6Tech The rank of the cofactors matrix is at most one more than the matrix' rank.